# using rpm -i in Linux as a normal user

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

I'm trying to run `rpm -i` to install an rpm but it fails. I must always use root to do the installation. why ?

> [alankoh@sjoam2 Downloads]$ rpm -i
>   sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch.rpm error: can't create transaction
>   lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock (Permission denied)

The rpm belong to the right user (alankoh:alankoh) with 664 permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal. All the system files – both the rpm database and the directories into which your `.rpm` would install stuff – are only modifiable by root. Who owns the `.rpm` file is not important.

Comment: Technically, one could make an rpm which installed *into* a wide-open directory.  But the rpm database requires privileged access to *update* it.

Comment: @ThomasDickey [root@localhost bin]# ls -l rpm -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 30600 Nov 22 2013 rpm [root@localhost bin]# I see that the rpm is own by root, but it allows others to execute it as well. So where is the part whereby a user does not have permission to it ?

Comment: The comment was not about the rpm *program*, but its *database* (files usually under `/var/lib/rpm`), which is owned by **root** and requires privileged access to *modify*.

Comment: @Thomas Dickey then how does a user install a program only for himself ? or how does a root install a program that can be usable only by a certain user ?

Comment: For oneself, usually that's put in `~/bin` (home directory).  The *root* user can install a program with specific user- and/or group-ownership to match a given user.